# Why does unmarshalling this API response return an unexpected EOF?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

### Problem

I'm creating a microservice in Go, using protocol buffers and gRPC. It interacts with a third-party API (Snooth) and I'm trying to unmarshal the JSON response into a protobuf struct I've created, using the `proto` package.

Unmarshalling returns an `unexpected EOF` error.

### What I've Tried

- Using `json.newDecoder` instead of `json.unmarshal`
- `jsonpb.Unmarshal` instead of `proto.Unmarshal` (returns a `bad value in StructValue for key` error)
- Limiting the response read with `io.LimitReader`

I've also read something about prefixing the proto types with a size tag or something? But I'm not sure what that is or if it's relevant. Here's the repo on [Github](https://github.com/lukeic/vinogo/tree/feature/snooth/snooth).

### Question

What is causing this `unexpected EOF` error and how do I fix it, so that the API response is successfully unmarshalled into the proto struct?

Side note: I am new to Go and would also appreciate any feedback/improvements on the following code. Thanks!

### Code

`Proto`

```
message Response {
    message Meta {
        int32 results = 1;
        int32 returned = 2;
        string errmsg = 3;
        int32 status = 4;
    }

    Meta meta = 1;
    repeated google.protobuf.Struct wines = 2;
    repeated google.protobuf.Struct actions = 3;
}
```

`main.go`

```
func fetchFromSnooth(e string, qs string, c chan response) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            log.Printf("Error fetching from Snooth: %s", r)
            errmsg := fmt.Sprint(r)
            c <- response{nil, snoothApiError{errmsg}}
        }
    }()

    v := url.Values{"akey": {os.Getenv("SNOOTH_API_KEY")}}
    requestUrl := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s/?%s%s", snoothRoot, e, v.Encode(), qs)
    log.Printf("Fetching: %s", requestUrl)

    res, err := httpClient.Get(requestUrl)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    result := &pb.Response{}
    if err := proto.Unmarshal(body, result); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c <- response{result, snoothApiError{""}}
}

func (s *snoothApiService) searchWines(params *pb.Parameters_WineSearch) response {
    c := make(chan response)
    defer close(c)

    v := url.Values{}
    go fetchFromSnooth("wines", v.Encode(), c)
    return <-c
}

func main() {
    snooth := snoothApiService{}
    resp := snooth.searchWines(nil)
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

### Edit

Here's an example of the type of API response I'm trying to unmarshal:

```
    {
    "meta": {
        "results": 1489442,
        "returned": 5,
        "errmsg": "",
        "status": 1
    },
    "wines": [
        {
            "name": "Conway Deep Sea Chardonnay la Costa Wine Co",
            "code": "conway-deep-sea-chardonnay-la-costa-wine-co-2008-1",
            "region": "USA > California > Central Coast",
            "winery": "Conway Family Wines",
            "winery_id": "conway-family-wines",
            "varietal": "Chardonnay",
            "price": "21.99",
            "vintage": "2008",
            "type": "White Wine",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.snooth.com\/wine\/conway-deep-sea-chardonnay-la-costa-wine-co-2008-1\/",
            "tags": "",
            "image": "https:\/\/ei.isnooth.com\/multimedia\/0\/2\/8\/image_787698_square.jpeg",
            "snoothrank": 3,
            "available": 0,
            "num_merchants": 0,
            "num_reviews": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "Olmaia Cabernet di Toscana",
            "code": "olmaia-cabernet-di-toscana",
            "region": "Italy > Tuscany > Toscana Igt",
            "winery": "Col D Orcia",
            "winery_id": "col-d-orcia",
            "varietal": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
            "price": "0.00",
            "vintage": "",
            "type": "Red Wine",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.snooth.com\/wine\/olmaia-cabernet-di-toscana\/",
            "tags": "",
            "image": "https:\/\/ei.isnooth.com\/multimedia\/d\/e\/e\/image_790198_square.jpeg",
            "snoothrank": 3.5,
            "available": 0,
            "num_merchants": 0,
            "num_reviews": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "Dominio Dostares Prieto Picudo Vino de la Tierra de Castilla Y León Cumal",
            "code": "dominio-dostares-prieto-picudo-vino-de-la-tierra-de-castilla-y-leon-cumal-2006",
            "region": "Spain > Castilla y León > Vino de la Tierra de Castilla y León",
            "winery": "Bischöfliches Priesterseminar Trier",
            "winery_id": "bischofliches-priesterseminar-trier",
            "varietal": "Prieto Picudo",
            "price": "15.89",
            "vintage": "2006",
            "type": "Red Wine",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.snooth.com\/wine\/dominio-dostares-prieto-picudo-vino-de-la-tierra-de-castilla-y-leon-cumal-2006\/",
            "tags": "",
            "image": "https:\/\/ei.isnooth.com\/multimedia\/d\/0\/4\/image_336595_square.jpeg",
            "snoothrank": "n\/a",
            "available": 0,
            "num_merchants": 0,
            "num_reviews": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Dominio Dostares Prieto Picudo Vino de la Tierra de Castilla Y León Cumal",
            "code": "dominio-dostares-prieto-picudo-vino-de-la-tierra-de-castilla-y-leon-cumal-2005",
            "region": "Spain > Castilla y León > Vino de la Tierra de Castilla y León",
            "winery": "Bischöfliches Priesterseminar Trier",
            "winery_id": "bischofliches-priesterseminar-trier",
            "varietal": "Prieto Picudo",
            "price": "38.99",
            "vintage": "2005",
            "type": "Red Wine",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.snooth.com\/wine\/dominio-dostares-prieto-picudo-vino-de-la-tierra-de-castilla-y-leon-cumal-2005\/",
            "tags": "",
            "image": "https:\/\/ei.isnooth.com\/multimedia\/1\/d\/a\/image_336596_square.jpeg",
            "snoothrank": "n\/a",
            "available": 0,
            "num_merchants": 0,
            "num_reviews": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "The Little Penguin Chardonnay Premier",
            "code": "the-little-penguin-chardonnay-premier-2010",
            "region": "South East Australia",
            "winery": "The Little Penguin",
            "winery_id": "the-little-penguin",
            "varietal": "Chardonnay",
            "price": "11.99",
            "vintage": "2010",
            "type": "White Wine",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.snooth.com\/wine\/the-little-penguin-chardonnay-premier-2010\/",
            "tags": "",
            "image": "https:\/\/ei.isnooth.com\/multimedia\/2\/c\/4\/image_826282_square.jpeg",
            "snoothrank": "n\/a",
            "available": 0,
            "num_merchants": 0,
            "num_reviews": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the response from the API is incomplete. Can you include the response you're trying to unmarshal in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### --Update--

I've now got the response unmarshalling as desired, using the `jsonpb.Unmarshal` method. To do so though I had to unmarshal and marshal the response with the regular json library first, in order to get around some escaped values in the response (I was receiving a 'bad value in Struct' error:

```
resJson, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

j := make(map[string]interface{})
if err := json.Unmarshal(resJson, &j); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

jbytes, err := json.Marshal(j)

result := &pb.Response{}
r := strings.NewReader(string(jbytes))
if err := jsonpb.Unmarshal(r, result); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: This was actually a bug in `jsonpb` itself, and has been fixed as per https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/605

Answer (score 3):

It DOES parse with then `encoding/json` package: https://play.golang.org/p/IQzMm2tDI7w

The `protoc`-generated code's `Unmarshal` parses a *Protocol Buffers* encoded byte stream, NOT JSON!

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're right, using the `json` package does decode the response into a generic map interface, however I'm trying to decode the response into a struct generated from a `.proto`. I've just tried `json.Unmarshal` together with a protobuf type of `repeated google.protobuf.Struct` for the `wines` key, but the result of `wines` is a bunch of empty, repeated maps.